# pt cruiser temperature gauge not working

Tags: temperature, pt-cruiser

The temp gauge does not work properly and in doing so with the heat on it blows cool.  When the car sits and idles the gauge will rise (sometimes) but, once you get moving it drops.  Just had the thermostat and head gasket replaced.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did it work before you had the thermostat and head gasket replaced? What was the diagnosis which lead to getting the work done in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it worked prior.  The car kept overheating and eventually blew the gasket.

Comment: If it worked  before you had the work done, then something the mechanic did (or didn't do) when replacing the parts wasn't done right. Take it back to them and tell them they didn't fix it completely.